# Multi Auth in Laravel to Use or Not to Use

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

We are developing an application with Laravel framework, it is supposed to be a RESTful Application which is implemented via the `resources` of Laravel framework,  given the following example:

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
{

public function __construct() {

}


public function index()
{        
    return response()->json($this->getAll());      
}


public function create()
{
    //
}


public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
}
```

Let's take the following example:
Some methods like `store` and `create` are only permitted by the admin of the website but `index` method is permitted by all the users and there are so many cases like this example-different type of users can only access some methods of a Contrller.

In this case we can either benefit from `Multi Auth` of Laravel and create different tables for the storing the users or define different type for users in the same table and handle users' access with `middleware` that apply to some specific functions

**Question:**
which way do you recommend and please provide the reasons behind your suggestion as well

Answer (score 3):

So, the answer depends on various parameters. The goal you're trying to achieve can be achieved using Laravel Multi-Auth or any RBAC (Role Based Access Control) system.

**Situations where you should use RBAC**: If your application is small you should go for any Role Based thing.
For Example.. Let's say you're working on some CMS then you won't create tables for each position (Manager, Developer, Marketing Head etc..) hence the RBAC is good option for you.

**Situations Where you should use Multi-Auth:** If your goal is big and you want to separate *user login* table and *admin login* table for any reason you can go for it.

**What I suggest**

What I suggest is to go for both, Multi auth as well as RBAC ( only if you're working on or trying to build very large scale application )

But as you're described, just keeping that in mind I would suggest you to go with RBAC not multi auth.

Some Useful links

[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2)
[RBAC](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/zizaco/entrust) (One of the Most Popular RBAC package for laravel)
If you feel like going for Multi Auth please follow This blog post [Multi-Auth with Laravel 5.2](http://imrealashu.in/code/laravel/multi-auth-with-laravel-5-2-2/)

If I'm missing something or the answer can be improved any way, feel free to comment.